# Making a button that shows a hidden image on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've found tutorials that make an image hidden with some css, javascript and html but I'm having trouble making the image hidden first, and then having the button be able to make it visible and then hidden if pressed again.

edit: hopefully this code should help! Again, sorry I can't figure some of this out, I don't really know how this site works and I'm pretty new to coding,,,,

edit 2: I added where the function is being called. It's suppose to be a multiple choice that shows an image when correct!

```html
<style>
div.notdropdown {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: rgb(181, 204, 180, 0.9);
}

.hide{
  display:none;
}
</style>
</body>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>



<div id="myDIV"> 
<img class= "hide" src="https://www.merriam-webster.com/assets/mw/static/art/dict/frig_bi.gif">
<br>
<a class= "hide" href="https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frigate%20bird">https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frigate%20bird </a>
<br>
</div>
```

```html
<h1>What is a Frigate?</h1><br>
<form >
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Bird"> A type of Bird
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Mangrove"> A type of Mangrove tree
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Sea Creature"> A type of Sea Creature
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="None"> None of These
</form>
<button onclick="submitAnswer();"> Submit Answer</button> 

</body>
```

```html
<script>

function submitAnswer() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("choice");
  var i = 0, len = radios.length;
  var checked = false;
  var userAnswer;

  for( ; i < len; i++ ) {
     if(radios[i].checked) {
       checked = true;
       userAnswer = radios[i].value;
     }
  } 

  if(!checked) {
    alert("please select choice answer");
    return;
  }
  // Correct answer
  if(userAnswer === "Bird") {
     myFunction();
     alert("Answer is correct!");


  }
  // incorrect answer
  else {
     alert("Answer is wrong!");
  }

}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your code.

Comment: Show us the code ...   This should be easy, but depends on which method you are trying to use.

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: So, you want to know how to hide a button using CSS?

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Share us a code or something

Comment: @Saniyasyedqureshi
sorry, im extremely new to coding and this website but I'm basically using the code from here
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show

Comment: Okay to add a **code** in your question....Start with ``` Your code content ```

Comment: @DaveAAA thank you! this is the code im using. the function gets called later on but I don't think its needed here since its the bulk of the code I need help with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact it's very simple, just use the toggle method, which allows you to easily enable and disable a class in an element

```js
function toggleImage(){
  document.querySelector('#image').classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}

.w-100{
  width: 100%;
}

.mb-10{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="toggleImage()" class="w-100 mb-10">Show/Hide</button>

<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" id="image" class="hidden w-100"/>
```

to work with a link to just change the tag to `a` and use `href="#"`

```js
function toggleImage(){
  document.querySelector('#image').classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}

.w-100{
  width: 100%;
}

.mb-10{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a onClick="toggleImage()" class="w-100 mb-10" href="#">Show/Hide</a>

<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" id="image" class="hidden w-100"/>
```

Comment: hi! i got this to work, tysm!
I was just wondering if there was a way for this to work on links as well? like a href?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call your function on button tag. Add a button in your html file on which you want your div to toggle. As you are using function name myFunction, call it on that function using
`onClick="myFunction()"`
And your code should work fine. Don't need to add any new class or even hide your div by default.

Comment: it still doesn't work? I have radio buttons set up and then on the submit button it has the "myFunction();" in with the if statement when it checks which button is correct

Comment: You need to use Javascript toggle method to toggle between the class.

Answer (score 0):

check this code. I think this will help you.

```
<button id = "showhide" onclick = "showhide()">Show Hide Image</button>

<div id = "image" style="width: 100px; height : 100px;"> 
    <h4> Image Code </h4>
</div>

<script>
    $('#showhide').on('click', function(e){
    $("#image").toggle();    
  });
</script>
```